# MySQL to MariaDB - Dynamic Columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-insert, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to transfer data from `old_table` to `table` with some of the data being in dynamic columns for future imports

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col_1`,`col_2`,etc....   `attributes`)
SELECT `col_1`,`col_2`,etc....     COLUMN_CREATE('name',`col_99` AS UNSIGNED,'name2',`col_100` AS CHAR)
FROM `old_table`
```

The only documentation on dynamic tables is basically

```
COLUMN_CREATE('name',1 AS UNSIGNED)
```

Which is not a very "dynamic" example...

Open to other solutions but NOT JSON, prefer MariaDB though as it is essentially MySQL which I'm used to

EDIT: many thanks for the answers, but for further information I am trying to use this approach documented (badly) here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns-functions/

Edit 2: I'm wondering whether EAV might be the only solution, as I seem to be hitting a wall with MariaDB Dynamic Columns, I can't find any more documentation or guides anywhere!

Edit 3: Not having any luck still with these dynamic columns? MariaDB is really confusing!

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic columns"?

Comment: To me this sounds like the wrong approach altogether :-(

Comment: Sorry, struggling to find the right words to explain. Basically, I could do what I need with about 200 columns with loads of null values... It doesn't need scope to increase in the number of columns necessarily, and 200 columns is possible, but it isn't an elegant solution. Also, the other method would be EAV approach, but again, it is inelegant and it doesn't need limitless numbers of columns, so I figured MariaDB has this dynamic columns thing, a bit like using JSON inside MySQL, but more searchable and therefore more elegant 

Comment: Would you care to explain (1) what the problem space is - such as product attributes, and (2) explain your aversion to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dynamic Columns, JSON, or EAV, you leave out NULL "columns".  You just include the items that are non-null.

I would recommend you abandon Dynamic Columns; they exist only that one place.  Meanwhile, JSON is becoming more accepted.  And even if you are using an "old" version of MariaDB or MySQL, you can put JSON text in a `TEXT` column.

Keep in mind that none of the eav-like techniques is very clean.

More on the problem space:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

As for "more searchable" -- You probably need to make compromises:

- Commonly searched fields: make into columns with `INDEXes`.
- Consider `FULLTEXT` index with some of the *text* data.  Just toss it all into a single text column for efficient searching.
- If you need to search too many different fields; use your application code to decode the JSON to finish the search (after you have filtered on what you can in SQL).
- That is, do not expect to do everything in SQL.

Comment: Do you mean JSON.column instead of Dynamic-column? Or just a json-string in some text/blob? I think Dynamic-columns might be faster, as they can have type-specifications for a field. (and iirc, json-column and dynamic-column are basically a BLOB anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col_1`, `col_2`, . . . col_99, col_100)
    SELECT `col_1`, `col_2`, . . ., 'name' as col_99, 
           CAST(NULL as char) as col_100  
    FROM `old_table`;
```

Just list the columns with their aliases; use constants for new columns.

Comment: Misprint - CASE instead of CAST. And this CAST is excess - the final datatype is already defined by the column specification in destination table. Aliases are excess too. Here's if it was a `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` query...

Comment: I understand this approach, but I am trying to use the MariaDB "COLUMN_ADD" dynamic columns, because I am transferring data from multiple old tables which have slightly different structure, the idea is to have something akin to an EAV approach, but since the possibilities are limited, rather than say a 200 column table with lots of nulls, I want to try and make a table with variable columns like the MariaDB documentation suggests